# R mgcv gam: variable can be used as a predictor but not as an offset - Why?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv, offset

I am trying to use the R mgcv package to fit a gam. I have one variable that I want to use as an offset. It works fine as a predictor, but when I use it as an offset gam fails with an error message about non-conformable arrays.

```
> x <- gam(gbf_3 == "G" ~ s(pred_lo) + s(avm_prop_21_mult), family=binomial(), weights=round(1000*wt), data=ma, subset=(!is.na(score_2)))
> x <- gam(gbf_3 == "G" ~ pred_lo + s(avm_prop_21_mult), family=binomial(), weights=round(1000*wt), data=ma, subset=(!is.na(score_2)))
> x <- gam(gbf_3 == "G" ~ offset(pred_lo) + s(avm_prop_21_mult), family=binomial(), weights=round(1000*wt), data=ma, subset=(!is.na(score_2)))
Error in x %*% coef + offset : non-conformable arrays
```

Why would a variable be acceptable as a predictor but not as an offset and what would I have to do to use the variable as an offset?

Thanks.

Ross

UPDATE

I can no longer reproduce the problem and I don't have access to the data because I don't work for that employer now.

It is possible that the problem was specific to the data set or that it was a problem with an earlier version of mgcv. The code below with mgcv 8.1-3 shows that it is syntactically correct to enter an offset with either an offset argument to the call or an offset term in the formula.

```
library("dplyr")
library("boot")
#
n <- 1000 # number of observations
df <- data.frame(p= runif(n), w= round(1000 * runif(n, min=1, max=2))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(y= sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size=1, prob= c(p, 1 - p)),
         o= logit(p))
#
# Check what is syntactically correct with glm() first
summary(glm(y ~ o, family=binomial, data=df)) # o is the best predictor
summary(glm(y ~ p, family=binomial, data=df)) # p is not so good as it is not properly scaled
summary(glm(y ~ p + offset(o), family=binomial, data=df)) # enter o as an offset in the formula
summary(glm(y ~ p, offset=o, family=binomial, data=df)) # enter o as an offset argument
#
# In glm() an offset can be entered in the formula with an offset() term or as an offset argument.
#
# Check what is syntactically correct with glm() first mgcv::gam()
library("mgcv")
#
summary(mgcv::gam(y ~ o, family=binomial, data=df)) # o is the best predictor
summary(mgcv::gam(y ~ p, family=binomial, data=df)) # p is not so good as it is not properly scaled
summary(mgcv::gam(y ~ p + offset(o), family=binomial, data=df)) # enter o as an offset in the formula
summary(mgcv::gam(y ~ p, offset=o, family=binomial, data=df)) # enter o as an offset argument
#
# In mgcv::gam() an offset can be entered in the formula with an offset() term or as an offset argument.
#
# Now try to reproduce the problem
#
x1 <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(o) + s(p), family=binomial(), weights=w, data=df, subset=(w < 1500))
x2 <- mgcv::gam(y ~ o + s(p), family=binomial(), weights=w, data=df, subset=(w < 1500))
x3 <- mgcv::gam(y ~ offset(o) + s(p), family=binomial(), weights=w, data=df, subset=(w < 1500))
#
# No error messages from the last line - so I can't reproduce the problem.
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have a simple syntax error. I can't what your modelling, but I believe the offset needs to be inside the parenthesis. For example, here's some code for a time series of counts:

```
P <- gam(COUNT~s(YEAR, fx =FALSE, bs ="ps"), family = poisson(link = log), 
     data = mydata, method="GCV.Cp", offset = LOG_POP, scale = -1)
```

Comment: Thanks NotMarkT, but it's not a syntax error. An offset can be entered as an offset argument or with an offset() term in the formula (see the code in my update above).